# click not working as expected

Tags: click, slidedown

I have this code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#list2').click(function() { 
  if ( !$('#text2').is(":visible") ){ 
$(".shownText").slideUp(100).removeClass('.shownText');
$('#text2').slideDown(500); 
}
    });
});
```

html for text2:

```
<div id="svceText">
<div id="text2" class="shownText">
<p>.......</p> </div>
</div>
```

html for list2:

```
<div id="svceContent">
<div id="list2"><h3><a href="">blah blah</a></h3></div>
</div>
```

Clicking on list2 isn't producing a correct slideDown on text2 - the top few pixels of text2 show, or nothing at all (different outcome with each click). Problem occurs in FF4/64bit and IE7/8/9.

Page can be viewed [HERE](http://lawyer.kirkfx.com/services2.html).

I've tried modifying the script to:

```
 $('#list2').bind('click', function() {
```

but no luck. Erghhh...

Comment: Can you provide some information regarding what is actually not working?

Comment: when click on any of the vertical list items, any text that is currently displayed in the svceText div should slide up, and new text should then slide down. If you hover on the top item in the list ("Collaborative Solutions"), you'll  see what should happen when you click on any of the other list items. [Note the bottom list item ("Contacts") is set to open a new page]

Comment: anyone? This is pretty important to my client. Cheers, Kirk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just had to put a hash/pound sign (`#`) in the href attribute for my anchor tags. Now the click functions works like a dream & I can get rid of the extraneous mouseover events that were making this web page a confusing mess.